# Total resistance of the following circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electrical-resistance

I am a student of class 10 and am unable to find the total resistance between points A and B of the following circuit. Anyone who knows how to do this, please guide me and provide a detailed answer.

[image]

Comment: this looks like bridge

Comment: The entire R R 4R R R thing in the upper part of the circuit goes to 0 (no current)-its a wheatstone bridge, leaving 3R, 3R AND 3R In the upper part-giving R for the upper part. Then, solve the bottom part, to get 3R/10, as the entire bottom part is connected to basically the same point on the side f B (equipotential points can be taken to be physically one), so the R, R R AND 3R are in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try and remove elements of the circuit where no current flows. Start with the diamond with the $4R$ resistor in the middle. What can you say about the current through the $4R$ resistor (**HINT**: Balanced Wheatstone bridge...).

If no current flows through a section of circuit, you can remove this section of circuit from the network.

You can actually simplify that diamond of 5 resistors into a single resistor if you follow the above through. Then, you end up with another balanced Wheatstone bridge (simplify the corners first...), and you can simplify the circuit further!

Follow the cycle of eliminating sections of circuit and simplifying, working outward from that middle diamond, and you will end up with a circuit which is much easier to solve.

Comment: I am still trying. As soon as I solve it, I will select your answer as the correct one. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @user12137152 where have you gotten up to so far?

Comment: The value I got is 0.3Ω. I request you to please check it whenever you feel free.

Comment: @user12137152 Yes that is what I obtained. Well done!